# Javascript cannot access 'value' of an element

Tags: javascript

I can't get the value from a variable by javascript and this don't appear in the code

[image]

[image]

I don't know how to search about it or to resolve this. My textbox don't alter the color, but receive the color and is not the cache.

[image]

Comment: There is no jQuery in your question. Post code, not images of code. Describe your problem properly with use of a [mcve]

Comment: With the details given it is difficult to make an educated guess, but it could be a timing issue - you are calling the function right away, and if this script block is above the element in your html, then it will not be found. If you already use jQuery, you could replace  `check();` by `$(check);`

Comment: @Chips_100 the first point you make makes sense, the second one about `$(check)` makes none

Comment: @Jamiec Not only does it makes sense, since jQuery 3.0 it is the recommended syntax for running a function when the DOM is fully loaded: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: You used the `getElementById()` method to returns the element. So for getting value from this element you should use `var varValue = element.value;` instead of `var varValue = element.val;`

Answer (score -1):

Thinking in a better way to make my code works I have developed the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkBatchQTD() {
        var element = document.getElementById('<%=txtlblBatchQTD.ClientID%>');
        var varValue = element.value;
        if (varValue == "") {
            element.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffc0";
        }
        else {
            element.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
        }
    }
</script>
```

And after do it I have searched for a way to make the function repeat and I have found the `window.setInterval` to make that function work with repeat:

```
<script>
    window.setInterval(function () {
        checkddlProduct();
        checkBatchQTD();
        checkDate();
    }, 500);
</script>
```

I'm so sorry if I don't have formated the question or not posted the code before this, but I thank you very much for the help.